# How to find the selected checkboxes from a listview?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have a listview with a checkboxes in each row. I am using the viewholder pattern to load the list, like this:

```
View view = convertView;
        if(view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting_list_item, null);

            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.cbCat = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbCat);

            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        vh.cbCat.setText(bt.getName());
```

But when I try to get the checked checkboxes, like this :

```
for(int i = lvCatList.getFirstVisiblePosition(); i < settingAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View v = lvCatList.getChildAt(i);
            CheckBox cbx = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.cbCat);

            if(cbx != null && cbx.isChecked()) {
                toast += " / " + settingAdapter.getItem(i).getName();
                Log.d("CHECKED", toast);
            }
```

Only the visible checkboxes can be get. And if the checkbox is not visible in the screen it throws exceptions.

How to check whether the chekboxes in the list are checked or not.?
            }

Comment: Define a boolean and fill it with the result from cbx.Checked?

Comment: @Rexxo can you elaborate your suggestion? Since I am getting exception in the not visible list item on screen.

Comment: @Harish 's link is good. Is your For loop working first and foremost? and try removing cbx != null.

Comment: @Rexxo I have implemented it in my app.It is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add selected checkbox value to arraylist when checking on checkbox

```
List<String> SelectedBox = new ArrayList<String>();

View.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if(isChecked)
            {
                SelectedBox.add(id);
            }
            else
            {
                SelectedBox.remove(id);
            }
    }
});
```

When you need to check whether the checkbox is checked just refer SelectedBox

Answer (score 2):

Refer the following example to get the checked item from listview.[ListView with checkbox](http://blog.marvinlabs.com/2010/10/29/custom-listview-ability-check-items/)